# How to apply custom style to AvalonDock

Tags: wpf, avalondock

Does anyone know how I can change the font properties of a title for LayoutAnchorable and LayoutDocument in AvalonDock 2.0? I would like to be able to apply a style that is used everywhere in my WPF application for consistency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a theme to use across your application. There are a couple of themes available in the AvalonDock distribution that can be used as an example or template to create your own (e.g. [VS2010 theme](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/100414#1749975)).

You then just apply it to your DockingManager:

```
<dock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager"
                     AnchorablesSource="{Binding DockModel.Tools}"
                     DocumentsSource="{Binding DockModel.Documents}"
                     ActiveContent="{Binding DockModel.ActiveContent, Mode=TwoWay}">

  <dock:DockingManager.Theme>
     <adCustom:DarkBlossomTheme />
  </dock:DockingManager.Theme>
  <dock:LayoutRoot/>
</dock:DockingManager>
```

Comment: Thanks, MrDosu. Thanks to you I saw that the DockingManager has an AnchorableHeaderTemplate property. As you can see I am new to AvalonDock and that property was enough for me. Anyway I will mark your response as an answer as it is generally better.